# Synonymize [tcp] and [tcp-ip]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Not really much to this one.

[tcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcp) tag description

> Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) is a transport layer protocol that provides a connection-oriented data stream service with guaranteed, in-order delivery.

[tcp-ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcp-ip) tag description

> TCP/IP is an acronym Transmission Control Protocol/Internet Protocol. It is a protocol stack that is responsible for endpoint-to-endpoint communications between two or more devices. Please use this tag if your question is specific to TCP/IP.

They're clearly referring to the same thing. [tcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcp) has ~15 times as many questions, so that makes sense as the one to merge into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’ve approved the pending synonym request, so [tcp-ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcp-ip) now redirects to [tcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcp), just like [tcpip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcpip) already does.